# Why am I getting undefined control sequence?

Tags: fonts, errors, baposter

This is where the issue lies:

```
{\includegraphics[height=5em]{UALOGO}
\hspace{1cm}}
{\includegraphics[height=5em]{NSFLOGO}}
{\textbf\textsc\Huge{Modeling the effects of crayfish invasion and drought on crayfish population dynamics
\vspace{0.125em}}}
```

Here are my headings:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.38]{baposter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\newcommand\myfigure[1]{
\medskip\noindent\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\end{minipage}\medskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\lf}[3]{$\frac{#1}{4}\alpha_1+\frac{#2}{4}\alpha_2+\frac{#3}{4}\alpha_3$}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{.9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{hanging}
\newcommand{\compresslist}{
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}
```

Comment: The right way to use bold is `\textbf{}` and the same for small caps, `\textsc{}`. Try `\textsc{\Huge Modeling the effects of crayfish invasion and drought on crayfish population dynamics}` inside your command. I guess that  the default font does not allow small caps in bold.

Comment: Undefined control sequence.
\in@ #1#2->\begingroup \def \in@@ 
                                  ##1#1{}\toks@ \expandafter {\in@@ #2{}{}#1...
l.115 \hspace{1cm}}

Comment: That's what the error says. I forgot to add that @Sigur

Comment: May be you have to get the includegraphics commands out of the brackets ({}} because I don't think that the hspace and the vspace can work in there... and leave at least an empty line after the vspace

Comment: Can you please complete your code to a single minimal document that shows the problem.

Comment: `\textbf\textsc\Huge{Modeling...}` is definitely incorrect. It should be either `\textbf{\textsc{\Huge Modeling...}}` or `{\bfseries\scshape\Huge Modeling...}`.

Comment: Two more problems with your code: (a) You shouldn't load both `color` and `xcolor`; I suggest you load only the latter. (b) You shouldn't load `colortbl` and `xcolor` independently; to assure full mutual compatibility, issue the single instruction `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE

Posting code fragments makes it difficult for people to help you. Please always post a full minimum working example beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Without this, it takes a lot of extra work to assist you, and particularly to pinpoint your issues.

The general structure of a `baposter` document is:

```
\documentclass[a0paper]{baposter}
\usepackage{...}
\begin{baposter}
{settings}
{Eye Catcher}
{Title}
{Author}
{University Logo}
\begin{posterbox}[name=box1, column=0, span=1]{Header}
Posterbox content
\end{posterbox}
\end{baposter}
\end{document}
```

The sequence `{Eye Catcher} {Title} {Author} {University Logo}` must be strictly adhered to. The code you posted does not follow this sequence, and `{author}` is missing.

Here is a complete MWE that includes various annotations on what the keys are doing. There are various corrections that follow comments made earlier. I would also encourage you to read the manual to see what each of the options actually does, and review other `baposter` answers posted on TeX.SE.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.38]{baposter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\newcommand\myfigure[1]{
\medskip\noindent\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\end{minipage}\medskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\lf}[3]{$\frac{#1}{4}\alpha_1+\frac{#2}{4}\alpha_2+\frac{#3}{4}\alpha_3$}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{.9}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,justification=centering]{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{hanging}
\newcommand{\compresslist}{
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}

\background{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    %the poster background color
    \fill[fill=blue!25!white] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
    %the header
    \fill [fill=orange!25!white] (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-\headerheight] current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}    

\begin{poster}{
        grid=false,
        columns=6, % how many columns 1-6
        colspacing=5.0mm, % spacing between the columns
        %        headerheight=0cm, % the height of the header for the title
        background=user, %user or none or plain
        headerheight=0.1\textheight,
        eyecatcher=true, %turn left logo on/off
        %posterbox environment options
        headerborder=closed, % see the baposter manual for the rest
        borderColor=darkgray,
        headershape=rectangle,
        headershade=plain,
        headerColorOne=green!40!white,
        textborder=rectangle,
        boxshade=plain,
        boxColorOne=green!10!white,
        headerFontColor=black,
        textfont=\scriptsize, % font definition for body of posterbox
        headerfont=\scshape, % font definition for header of posterbox
        linewidth=1pt,
    }
    {\includegraphics[height=5em]{example-image-a}\hspace{1cm}} % Eyecatcher on the left
    {\bfseries\scshape Modeling the effects of crayfish invasion and drought on crayfish population dynamics
            \vspace{0.125em}} % Title - the default font size is \Huge - there are few bold small cap fonts so adding \bfseries will depend on which font is chosen. Here it does nothing.
    {Author} % Author - the default font size is \Large
    {\includegraphics[height=5em]{example-image-b}} % Logo
\begin{posterbox}[name=box1, column=0, span=1]{Header}
    Some text
\end{posterbox}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image]